# Why the record rules are not working as expected Odoo 10?

Tags: record, odoo, odoo-10, rules

I am using odoo 10. I want to restrict the project users to see or edit their own tasks only. And the project manager can assign tasks to them and can see all the tasks. That means project manager should have full permissions.

I tried many solutions from the forums but none of them are working as expected. Any help is highly appreciated.

I have created a new record rule:

- Object: `project.task`
- Domain filter: `[('user_id','=',user.id)]`

When I save it as global then each task is seen by its assignee only but this rule is applying for project manager also. Project manager also not able to see or create his tasks for his team now. But I need project manager to have full permissions.

If I select the group as Project/User: In this case the effect is gone and all the users are able to see all tasks.

Also I have created a record rule for Project/Manager with domain filter `[(1, '=', 1)]`. But still my required result is not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the documentation about [**Odoo Security**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html) carefully. Basically Odoo provides two main data-driven mechanisms to manage or restrict access to data.

- Access Control
- Record Rules

In your case you just need to copy the setting from other similar case. For example "Sales Manager" and "User: Own Documents Only" for sales.

1. **Access Control**. Create both groups and give permission to the model, in your case `project.tasks`

   [image: access rights]
2. **Rules**. Add a rule only for the "User: Own Documents Only", in your case "Project/User":

   [image: rule]

Answer (score 0):

Read this carefully. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/security.html

> Global rules are subtractive, they must all be matched for a record to be accessible
>
> Group rules are additive, if any of them matches (and all global rules match) then the record is accessible

Turns out the global rules are subtractive, the group rules are additive. If you apply globally then only users that satisfy your domain user_id = user.id will be readable/writable. But if you apply only to a group, it won't restrict the access because it's additive and users are granted access somewhere else.

What I did for a similar scenario is apply a global rule so that
task is only seen by its assignee. Then apply a group rule to manager so that manager can see all tasks.

Hope this could help you